# R loop through subfolders

Tags: r, loops, directory, filepath

i have a parent folder containing many sub-folders. I need to read a file in each sub-folder. the file name is Aligned.bam which is identical across all sub-folders.  is there a way I can generate all the file paths for this file. so that I can write a loop function to read each bam file.

```
parent.folder <- '/N/slate/ATACseq'
subfolders <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=TRUE)[-1]
subfolders/Aligned.bam--------->need something like this.
```

how to achieve this in R?

Comment: Searching even extensive searching is expected of questioners, even first time questioners. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592  Seems very likely this has been asked before. Have you looked at any of the almost 300 items in SO that involve `[r]` and `list.dirs`? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+list.dirs

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing:

```
Files <- list.files(path = "full_path_to_parent_folder", pattern = "Aligned.bam$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

This would output the paths to all Aligned.bam in your desired parent folder set in `path`.